# Two-tiered JQuery Chained dropdown boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm attempting to get a 2 tiered dropdown box using the JQuery chain selector from:
(http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained)

**also I've started using jsfiddle but I'm having issues getting the json to spit out data** http://jsfiddle.net/b1ackjosh/2STbh/2/

my json appears to be working but I can't tell why my second stage dropbox(pversion) isn't populating.

here's the json:

```
[{"vname":"3.11.1"}]
```

the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#pversion").remoteChainedTo("#productname", "../mybin/json.asp");    
});
</script>
```

vbscript code:

```
<select id="productname" name="productname">
  <option selected="">--Product Name--</option>
<%
Dim rstVer, rstVerParent, rstVerQ
Set rstVerParent = SQLQuery(cnnDB,"SELECT * FROM productversion where Parent is null")
If Not rstVerParent.EOF Then
Do While Not rstVerParent.EOF
%>
  <option><%= rstVerParent("vname") %></option>
<%
rstVerParent.MoveNext
Loop
End If
%>
</select>

<select id="pversion" name="pversion">
   <option>--Version Number--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you include both the jquery JS and the `remoteChainedTo` plugin's JS files? Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Yes(to your first question), and no there aren't any errors in the console which is what's tripping me up. It appears to work as the second box becomes inactive when I select an option from the first box. However it seems that it must be looking for something specific from the JSON data that I'm not picking up on. Hence the second dropbox being greyed out.